# How to get the date only on datetime on c# and putnit on database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013

I was working on an information system that gathers the students information for the teachers. One part of it is outting the value of the datetime picker on the db via command.parameters.addwithvalue. So I'm asking if there is any way to parse the datetime oicker so that there would be only date appearing on the db. Currently, date and time (set date and 12:00:00 am is showing.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, you want to use the `data` datatype - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 .

Comment: Why do you need to store only date? You can get datetime from your db and display only this part that you need (date, time or both)

Comment: @mjwills Sql2016 on vs2013 itself.

Comment: @pawet the date mentioned is birthday.

Comment: Did you try to simply format the DateTime from the DateTimePicker? i.e. dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL2016, can use the data type `date` instead of `datetime` if you don't need the time.  If the column's datatype is `datetime`, you will always have a time associated with it (if you just provide SQL a date for the value, it will set the time to midnight - 00:00:00).

Date and Time datatypes in SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#DateandTimeDataTypes

If you don't wan't to (or if you can't) change the data type in the database, then on the C# side you can at least make sure that all the times are normalized to midnight from a datetimepicker by using `ControlName.Value.Date` where ControlName is the name of your datetimepicker control.  *(Having all times normalized to midnight can make SQL query writing easier when all you really need is the date but you're stuck with a datetime data type)*

DateTime.Date property in .net: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I Have a C# function for this issue also;

```
    public String ArrangeDate (string S) 
    {
        FirstPoint = S.IndexOf(".");
        SecondPoint =S.IndexOf(".",FirstPoint+1); 
        S= S.Substring(SecondPoint+1,4) + "-" +S.Substring(FirstPoint+1,SecondPoint-FirstPoint-1)+ "-" + S.Substring(0,FirstPoint);
        return S;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send datetimepicker text to Stored Procedue  like  varchar parameter with time.
And parse it in SP like this

```
    create SP 
    @Date varchar(50)
    as

      declare @DateX smalldatetime

      select @DateX=Convert(smalldatetime,substring(@Date,7,4)  +'-' + substring(@Date,4,2) +'-' + substring(@Date,1,2))
```